# Возможно ли ускорить копирование данных между таблицами?

Tags: mysql, база-данных

Есть две таблицы **А** и **B**. **A** - 300 млн. и **B** - 30 млн записей.
Нужно скопировать из таблицы **A** в **B** записи за день, ~100 тысяч.

Если использовать стандартный подход `INSERT` + `SELECT` данный запрос занимает несколько часов. Есть ли другие варианты выполнить данные действия, которые существенно увеличат скорость выполнения?

*p.s.* в доп. таблице **C** ~100к записей, запрос в условии возвращает ~50к.

*Текущий запрос*

```sql
INSERT INTO B
SELECT
       id,
       col1,
       col2,
       day,
       ...
FROM A
WHERE day = '2023-08-14' AND col1 IN (
       SELECT col1 FROM C WHERE col1 IS NOT NULL
);
```

*Explain*

| id | select_type | table | partitions | type | possible_keys | key | key_len | ref | rows | filtered | Extra |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | INSERT | B | null | ALL | null | null | null | null | null | null | null |
| 1 | SIMPLE | C | null | range | col_1 | col_1 | 9 | null | 14604 | 100 | Using where; Using index; Start temporary |
| 1 | SIMPLE | A | null | ref | ci1 | ci1 | 40 | const | 146884 | 10 | Using where; End temporary |

*Таблица А*

```sql
create table A
(
    id    int unsigned auto_increment primary key,
    day   char(10)                       not null,
    col_1  varchar(32)                    null,
    col_2  varchar(48)                    null,
    col_3  varchar(48)                    null,
    col_4  varchar(128)                   null,
    col_5  varchar(48)      default ''    null,
    col_6  varchar(32)                    null,
    col_7  char(2)          default 'NA'  not null,
    col_8  varchar(256)                   not null,
    col_11 int unsigned                   not null,
    col_12 int unsigned     default '0'   not null,
    col_13 int unsigned     default '0'   not null,
    col_14 int unsigned     default '0'   not null,
    col_15 decimal(12, 3)   default 0.000 not null,
    col_16 decimal(12, 3)   default 0.000 not null,
    col_17 decimal(12, 3)   default 0.000 not null,
    col_18 decimal(12, 3)   default 0.000 not null,
    col_19 decimal(12, 3)   default 0.000 not null,
    col_20 tinyint unsigned default '50'  not null,
    col_21 tinyint unsigned default '0'   not null,
    col_9  tinyint unsigned default '1'   not null,
    col_22 tinyint unsigned default '0'   not null
)
    collate = utf8mb4_general_ci;

create index ci1
    on A (day, col_6, col_9);
```

*Таблица B*

```sql
create table B
(
    id    int unsigned           not null primary key,
    day   char(10)               not null,
    col_1  varchar(32)            null,
    col_2  varchar(48)            null,
    col_3  varchar(48)            null,
    col_4  varchar(128)           null,
    col_5  varchar(48) default '' null,
    col_6  varchar(32)            null,
    col_7  char(2)                not null,
    col_8  varchar(256)           not null,
    col_9  tinyint unsigned       not null,
    col_10 tinyint unsigned       null
)
    collate = utf8mb4_general_ci;

create index ci1
    on B (day, col_1, col_6, col_9);

create index col10
    on B (col_10);

create index day_col1
    on B (day, col_1);
```

*Таблица С*

```
create table C
(
    id    int unsigned auto_increment primary key,
    col_1 bigint unsigned null,
    constraint col_1
        unique (col_1)
)
    collate = utf8mb4_general_ci;
```

Comment: insert 100k записей не может занимать несколько часов. Значит все время занимает скорее всего сам select этих записей. А если так, то надо задавать себе вопрос "как ускорить select". Для ответа на который надо посмотреть план выполнения запроса, есть ли индексы например на поле day. Еще бы не помешало посмотреть какой в таблице первичный ключ и какова его изменивость у записей за 1 день

Comment: ну и вот этот вот IN в запросе, там в подзапросе сколько записей примерно

Comment: Просто для ориентировки. У меня на лэптопе импорт из csv и xml в Access 5,8 млн. небольших записей занимает 90 с. Это сравнение так себе, конечно, но видать с SELECTом в запросе совсем худо. Если подзапрос возвращает 50 т. записей, а копируется 100 т., то это получается 50 т. выборок по 2 записи. Наверно, не самый производительный вариант.

Comment: А если вместо IN сделать JOIN?

Comment: Спрашивая о производительности, выкладывайте полные структуры таблиц и EXPLAIN запроса. *Текущий запрос* - синтаксически ошибочен (опечатка?). В любом случае - избавиться от WHERE IN.

Comment: @Akina, дополнил вопрос.
Как "избавится" от WHERE IN?

Comment: А он там вообще нужен ? у вас бывают в таблице A записи у которых col1 не null и значения которых нет в таблице C ?

Comment: Сравните времена выборки `select count(1) FROM A WHERE ...` с текущим условием, потом то же но без IN, и еще без IN но с col1 is not null и заодно количество записей сравните. Но время больше всего интересует в таких вариантах.

Comment: 1) Посмотрите, сколько времени занимает один селект, без инсерта, возможно, этому запросу не хватает индексов 2) Попробуйте удалить/задисейблить индексы в таблице `B` перед записью в неё (в разных БД делается по-разному), а после записи восстановить их (у вас индексы по текстовым полям, вполне возможно тормозит их постоянное перестроение при инсерте) 3) Но если таблица `B` должна при этом использоваться ещё какой-то программой и индексы нужны, то нужно уже смотреть видимо в сторону `bulk insert`, опять же я не знаю, есть ли оно в `mysql`

Comment: @Mike В таблице А col_1 может быть пустым и не все записи подходят для импорта.

Comment: ну то что оно может быть пустым понятно. но могут ли там быть значения которых нет в "C"

Comment: И вы времена все таки всех 3 вариантов where померяйте. потому что они скажут в какую сторону двигаться. А то в вдруг у вас записи в пределах одного дня не с близкими id и тогда мы получим огромное время даже просто на day='' без всяких in и тогда мероприятия для ускорения будут совсем другими ...

Answer (score 0):

А если вместо IN сделать JOIN?

```
INSERT INTO B
SELECT
       id,
       col1,
       col2,
       day,
       ...
FROM A INNER JOIN C ON A.col1=C.col1
WHERE day = '2023-08-14' AND col1 NOT NULL;
```

Не уверен, понадобится "AND col1 NOT NULL" или нет. Зависит от содержимого A.

Comment: @Akina Хорошо, что есть знающие люди - поправят, если что. А то мысли растекаются от жары...